# What is the best way to replace ndt localization with gps localization in AutowareAuto?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am planning on replacing ndt localization with rtk corrected gps localization for AutowareAuto release 1.0.0.

I see that there is a new package called gnss_conversion_nodes which is not in 1.0.0 and it converts WGS84 coordinates to  ECEF then fills up a autoware_auto_msgs::msg::RelativePositionWithCovarianceStamped and publishes it. https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/blob/master/src/tools/gnss_conversion_nodes/design/gnss_conversion_nodes-design.md. The published message contains position in 3D in ECEF earth coordinates but no orientation.

Also I have noticed that ndt based localization publishes pose as a geometry_msgs::msg::PoseWithCovarianceStamped which is not the same as  autoware_auto_msgs::msg::RelativePositionWithCovarianceStamped which gnss_conversion_node publishes. Shouldnt the two msg types be the same so that gnss_conversion_nodes be a direct replacement of ndt_nodes?

Assuming we get gnss_conversion_nodes running, next step is to provide a static_transform_publisher to provide the conversion from ECEF earth coordinates to map coordinates similar to PCD map loader.

ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher x y z r p y earth map

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382182/what-is-the-best-way-to-replace-ndt-localization-with-gps-localization-in-autowareauto?/) by [asobhy](https://answers.ros.org/users/53222/asobhy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is what I have done:

create a gps imu node. the node combines gps position and imu orientation into a geometry_msgs::msg::PoseWithCovarianceStamped then publishes this data. In addition to that the node also needs to publish the map to odom transform in order for the tf tree to be complete. the map to odom transform can be achieved through this set of transformations: map to earth then earth to base link then base link to odom, which are all already available through tf2_ros::BufferClient::lookupTransform

Additionally a static earth to map publisher needs to publish the tf, which is done from command line for now.

Just a heads up for anyone doing the same project the GPS data on LGSVL is not aligned properly and I have created an issue for it here https://github.com/lgsvl/simulator/issues/1597

---

Originally posted by [asobhy](https://answers.ros.org/users/53222/asobhy/) with karma: 31 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sujithvemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/86729/sujithvemi/) on 2021-12-28**:
Hi, I had implemented the node according to your suggestions, it was really helpful. But one thing is not clear to me, is the lookupTransform capable of finding the /map->/odom transform by itself? Because in my implementaiton /earth->/base_link is not readily available as you have mentioned in your answer. Should I publish that transform using the GNSS data we get, if so would the orientation be IMU data directly received? It would be really helpful if you can shed some more light on the transforms part. Thank you.